# Fullcalendar - two Ajax callbacks

Tags: asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar

I am struggling with situation of geting events from two different resources. I know that as ajax is asynchronous I cant get more than one callbacks and my code is proving that - By reloading the page I am getting random results from one or other query. But there must be some workaround, right? I just wanna get combined array of both events and vacations so I can pass it to fullcalendar as one instance. Thanks a lot!

```
var events = [];
            var vaca = [];
            var now = moment();
            var nextMonth = now.clone().add(1, 'month');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        //alert(v.id);
                        events.push({
                            title: v.title,
                            description: "Project Type: " + v.projectType,
                            start: moment(v.onSite),
                            end: v.onSiteTill != null ? moment(v.onSiteTill).add('days', 1) : null,
                            color: v.color,
                            allDay: true
                        });

                    })

                    GenerateCalendar(events);

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');

                }

            })

 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetVacations",
                success: function (data2) {
                    $.each(data2, function (i, v) {
                        //alert(v.who);
                        vaca.push({
                            title: v.who,
                            description: ("Who or what: " + v.who + ". Vacation because " + v.why).link("Vacation/Edit/" + v.id),
                            start: moment(v.fromWhen),
                            // add one day due to excluding end date in callendar
                            end: v.tillWhen != null ? moment(v.tillWhen).add('days', 1) : null,
                            color: "#cc0000",
                            allDay: true
                        });

                    })

                    GenerateCalendar(vaca);

                },

                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');

                }

            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call next Ajax call from first AJAX call.
Sample Code for Reference:

```
            $.ajax({url: URL, data : {//data
            }).done( function( data ) {
                // Handles successful responses only
            }).fail( function( error) {
                console.log( error);
            }).then( function( data ) {   // Promise finished
                $.ajax( { //2nd ajax
                    url :  URL,
                    data : { DATA }
                }).done( function( data ) {
                        // 2nd call finished
                }).fail( function( reason ) {
                     console.log( error);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you. This one helped!

Answer (score 0):

Generate your calendar first then make 2 calls to render the events. You can use the FullCalendar [renderEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvent) or [renderEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvents) to achieve this.

I have created a basic working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qASyxV).

Comment: Why was my answer accepted then unaccepted? Why wait for the first request to complete before firing the second? On a slow connection it would appear less responsive to the user.